# How can I restrict my ActiveRecord query to ALL in array?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called `Color` and a model called `Item`. They are joined by a table `item_colors`.

I have some items that are `blue`, some that are `red`, and some that are `blue and red` through associations.

if I have an array like this: `array = [:red, :blue]`

I would like to get all items with that have a `red` color AND a `blue` color, but every query I try returns items that have `red` OR `blue` colors.

How can I restrict the query to `AND` so it excludes those that don't match all colors in the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a scope with a custom sql query.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_colors
  has_many :colors, through: :item_colors
  scope :find_by_colors, -> (*colors) do
    find_by_sql ["SELECT items.id, items.name FROM item_colors INNER JOIN items ON item_colors.item_id = items.id INNER JOIN colors ON item_colors.color_id = colors.id WHERE colors.name IN (?) GROUP BY items.name HAVING COUNT(item_colors.id) = ?;", colors, colors.count]
  end
end
```

Use the scope.

```
Item.find_by_colors("red", "blue")
```